# Fetch large number of rows from Dynamodb

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

We have around 6 billion rows in Dynamodb and would like to build a process where we need to fetch portion of data in each cycle. Let's say that portion is between 5 million and 10 million of rows. Data in Dynamodb is organized by primary key which is some hash value and sorting key date of occurrence. We need to extract for certain collection of hash values all of the data from Dynamodb. What are my options to do this extraction in a fastest possible way?

For now Aws Glue is out because they do not support pushdown predicates. Other option we are thinking is dividing input data into several smaller chunks and each chunk goes to new lambda instance which basically does BatchGetItem. Do you have any advice in which direction to go?

Answer (score 0):

You could look at using [AWS EMR](https://aws.amazon.com/emr/) with [Apache Hive](https://hive.apache.org/).

By doing this you can [load your DynamoDB tables as an external table](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/EMRforDynamoDB.html) and then perform normal SQL like syntax to perform queries.

Comment: Problem there is that I basically have serverless architecture. Orchestrating everything with step functions, running Apache Spark on Glue, populating Dynamodb with DMS and also using Lambda, Sagemaker and so on. Correct me if I'm wrong, in this setup your solutions would seem more like one time manual action to do some data extraction from Dynamodb and not an automated action that would do N times per day.

Comment: Use AWS DataPipeline to schedule your job in EMR, see: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-manage-recurring.html

Comment: Thank you! What do you think about running Lambda and BatchGetItem? Input can be divided into several chunks each consuming separate Lambda instance.

Comment: Its feasable, but you'd want to make sure memory/CPU requirements are there. It could  require many invokes to complete.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach of
"dividing input data into several smaller chunks and each chunk goes to new lambda instance which basically does BatchGetItem"

Can work but you would require fleet of lambdas to process your data. Here one thing you can consider is using pywren which is also suggested by aws team.

Pywren manages the fleet of lambda for you and provide you with the results you expected in far less time..

You can go through this [here](http://pywren.io)

Here is a link to samples provided by aws
https://github.com/aws-samples/pywren-workshops

Comment: Thanks Jain. When you say fleet what do you reckon? My thought is to go per 25k in one csv file. For million rows that would be 40 files and 40 parallel lambda runs.I also must mention that we do everything using .net and Scala and our whole architecture is done using this 2 languages and of course yaml :)

Comment: By fleet I mean parallel runs of lambda...well this is for python and it provides upto 60 Gbps write speed on s3.. but this is available for python only.. Still you can write your own logic to create parallel lambdas.